# What to teach first: Riemann sums or anti-derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, education, riemann-sum

In some text books, I see that they teach Riemann sums first. In other texts, I see they teach anti-derivatives first.

Is there any pedagogical preference? It seems to me that we should teach Riemann sums first to understand the point of integrals.

Thoughts?

Comment: This should be posted on matheducators.SE

Comment: Just a student's perspective: 
When I started learning calculus last year I learned antiderivatives then Riemann sums, and I have to say that the order made no sense to me. It was like teaching someone to ride a bike and afterwards showing them how to ride with training wheels.

Comment: I agree with Sky in his remark. When I started teaching, everybody was doing antiderivatives followed by the definite integral. When I turned the order around, I felt much better. There was a reason to teach antiderivatives when we knew the fundamental theorem.

Comment: When did it get to be called a Riemann sum? Newton and Liebnitz developed calculus,especially its fundamental theorem, independently in the 17th century.Riemann was one of the greatest mathematicians ever but was 200 years later. In between there were the Bernoullis, Euler, Gauss, Fourier, Cauchy, and a horde of others, all doing calculus. I doubt that you are starting with  Riemann integration itself.

Comment: @user254665, who first used $\Delta x$ in finite sums that approximate integrals?

Comment: @user254665 Their versions of calculus were incredibly flawed and mistaken in many ways. Calculus was revamped in the early 1800s into something which much more closely resembles that of what we do today. They get credit for the ideas, of course, but the monickers go to the mathematicians who revamped it into what we know today.

Answer (score 2):

The historical order is the pedagogical order.

1. Areas and any other relevant ideas from geometry, treated informally
2. d(Area under graph of $f$) = $f(x)$ by the visual geometric argument.
3. Antiderivatives are therefore useful.  Polynomials etc.
4. Riemann sum as discrete approximation, as formalization of "area" concept, as motivation for "dx", and as method to compute limits of some finite sums by taking integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The anti-derivative us the "opposite procedure" than that of the derivative, therefor it makes sense to do it after the derivative. The integral however is the area under a curve for the given interval and Riemann Sums explain why it is (amazingly) the difference between the values of the anti-derivative at the two endpoints of the interval.

So before you can understand Integrals, you have to understand the anti-derivative, then Riemann sums as the approximate area under the curve.

So it makes sense for me to do

1. Derivatives
2. Anti-derivatives
3. Riemann Sums
4. Integrals

Well at least that's how I finally made sense of it when I was tutoring Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

To take a contrarian point of view, there's merit in starting with antiderivates too. It all depends on which application you have in mind. For example if it's for physics the interrest of the area under the graph is often a distraction because what's actually the point is the solution of an ODE.

So if you put ODE's into the picture as something useful to learn you may want to introduce the problem of solving ODE's and see how antiderivates are part of the solution.

I noted that some complained that something didn't make any sense, but that may also be due to the road-map hasn't been conveyed yet. I think one problem may be that the student doesn't see the larger picture while doing Calculus, perhaps not even after taking the course. I think one should convey the roadmap before starting. If that's being done it's probably easier to alter the order without it loosing sense.